# ruby requiring active_record slows down script startup to 30 seconds

Tags: ruby, windows, performance, activerecord

I wrote a script to use active_record without rails. My tests are on windows 7 (Trendmicro Virus protection enabled - can't disable it because the notebook is property of my company), Lenovo T520. I wrote a little tk script that started in about a second. I added the 'sqlite3' gem and it started in 2 seconds.

After requiring the 'active_record' gem startup time when up to 30 seconds!!

Can I do something against that (please don't recommend changing the os)? Is ruby just for use with rails so that it can run on a unix box where the performance is ok?

Versions are:
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
activerecord (3.2.2)

Edit: Something interesting happened. After starting the script a few times "requiring 'active_record'" is done in 0.53 seconds. Maybe it's os-caching or virus protection ignores the files because it considers them safe. After a fresh reboot the time went up to 3.5 seconds on the first run and dropped again on the second run to the known 0.53 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) instead of ActiveRecord? Ruby is fine for general scripting but ActiveRecord isn't exactly lightweight or quick to start up.

Comment: Ok, requiring just dm-core boils it down to 12 seconds. That is almost acceptable. But somehow I'm still annoyed. I thought writing a an data centric application on windows with a scripting language like ruby would be completely possible. But I'm struggling already at step zero. I understand, that I have to pay for a orm framework. But 12 seconds just to start it up without doing anything with it is a pain in the ass (at least while developing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an somehow acceptable solution. It depends on the order the modules are required:

Startup 30 seconds:
require 'tk'
require 'active_record'

Startup 2 seconds:
require 'active_record'
require 'tk'

IMHO this thing is answered (but I'm not really satisfied).